# Fetching and updating data from a database

Tags: codeigniter-2

I want to fetch and update data from database using codeigniter. I am facing some problem. This is my code:

This is my Model by the name of Update_site_model.

```
<?php
class update_site_model extends CI_Model{   
    function show_invoice_id($data) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('invoices');
        $this->where('invoiceId', $data);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result;

    //Update Query For Selected Invoice.
    function update($id,$data) {
    $this->db->where('invoiceId',$id);
    $this->db->update('invoices',$data);    
    }
}
?>
```

This is my Controller by the name of update site.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Update_site extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->view('includes/header');
        $this->load->view('site/update');
        $this->load->view('includes/footer');

        //load the model
        $this->load->model('update_site_model');

    }

    function show_invoices() {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $data['single_invoice'] = $this->update_site_model->show_invoice_id($id);
        $this->load->view('site/update', $data);
    }

    function update() {
        $id = $this->input->post('invoiceId');
        $data = array(
        'Date' => $this->input->post('invoiceDate'),
        'Client' => $this->input->post('invoiceClient'),
        'Amount' => $this->input->post('invoiceAmount'),
        'Status' => $this->input->post('invoivceStatus')
        );

        $this->update_site_model->update($id, $data);
    }
}
```

This is my view by the name of update. it is inside a folder by the name of site.

```
 <div id="content">

    <ol>
        <?php foreach ($invoices as $invoice): ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/Update_site/show_invoice_id" . $invoice->invoiceId; ?>"><?php echo $invoice->invoiceId; ?></a></li>
    </ol>
        <?php endforeach; ?>    

    </div>
```

and this is the problem.

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: invoices
>
> Filename: site/update.php
>
> Line Number: 11
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: site/update.php
>
> Line Number: 11

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Please choose a more descriptive title.

Comment: Beware, you're using $invoice twice in your foreach statement. You'd rather have foreach($invoice as $invoices) ?

Comment: Thanks dear Rubik but this hadn't solved the problem still the same error is coming for me

Answer (score -1):

Look at this in your controller:

```
 $data['single_invoice'] = $this->update_site_model->show_invoice_id($id);
```

and now look at this in your view:

```
<?php foreach ($invoices as $invoice): ?>
```

did you got your mistake..?

no..?

let me tell you , since you are storing the database result in `$data['single_invoice']`  you should access this by `$single_invoice` in the view.

so correct usage in your view is :

```
<?php foreach ($single_invoice as $invoice): ?>
```

and next time when you ask any question give appropriate title to it.